# How to close an activity (finish()) from service?

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

i make a lock screen application.. i have some service that listen to the SMS.. when the SMS receiving command andro-lock then i display a lock screen that called by service:
here'e the service's code :

```
 if (tempMessage[0].toString().equalsIgnoreCase("andro-lock") && tempMessage[1].toString().equals(tempPassword.toString())) 
                            {
                                //Toast.makeText(ListenSMSservice.this, "Menjalankan command andro-lock", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                openDatabase();
                                updateStatusL();
                                Intent myIntent = new Intent(ListenSMSservice.this,LockScreenForm.class);
                                myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                getApplication().startActivity(myIntent);
                            }
```

that code has works perfecly, but i have some problem when i try to unlock my phone.. if my service receive command andro-unlock then i must close (finish) that lockscreen.java.. i was trying many code and still not works.. what must i do to close the lockscreen activity when my service receiving command andro-unlock?? please help..

```
else if (tempMessage[0].toString().equalsIgnoreCase("andro-unlock") && tempMessage[1].toString().equals(tempPassword.toString()))   
                            {
                                //what must i do??
                                //any solution??

                            }
```

Thanks for your help..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution to stop the activity would be:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(ListenSMSservice.this,LockScreenForm.class);
myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
Bundle myKillerBundle = new Bundle();
myKillerBundle.putInt("kill",1);
myIntent.putExtras(myKillerBundle);
getApplication().startActivity(myIntent);
```

In `LockScreenForm`

```
onCreate(Bundle bundle){
if(this.getIntent().getExtras().getInt("kill")==1)
    finish();
}
```

Comment: public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.lockscreen);
        
        if(bundle.getInt("kill")==1)
        {
            finish();
        }
    }

@sherif: still error.. sorry, because i'm still newbie in android.. any other solution??

Comment: hehe change savedInstanceState to bundle

Comment: so it becomes onCreate(Bundle bundle)

Comment: still not works and give me some "force close" any other solution bro?? really need thath code.. :(

Comment: public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.lockscreen);
        
        if(bundle.getInt("kill")==1){
         finish();
        }
        
    }

Comment: error in this section if(this.getIntent().getExtras().getInt("kill")==1){
            //finish();
        }

Comment: that code gave me an error "The application LockScreen (process com.application.LockScreen) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again.

Comment: public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.lockscreen);
        
        if(this.getIntent().getExtras().getInt("kill")==1){
         try {
          finish();
   } catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
    Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), 1).show();
   }
      
  }
}
@sherif this is my final code and it still not works

Comment: what did you put in `else if (tempMessage[0].toString().equalsIgnoreCase("andro-unlock") && tempMessage[1].toString().equals(tempPassword.toString()))    `

Comment: i put this code:
Intent myIntent = new Intent(ListenSMSservice.this,LockScreenForm.class);
                          myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                          Bundle myKillerBundle = new Bundle();
                          myKillerBundle.putInt("kill",1);
                          myIntent.putExtras(myKillerBundle);
                          getApplication().startActivity(myIntent);

Comment: yes it'w very weird sherif.. is my code placement in lockscreen.java are correct? i'm affraid that the placement is incorrect..
Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.lockscreen);
        
        if(this.getIntent().getExtras().getInt("kill")==1){
         try {
          finish();
   } catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
    Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), 1).show();
   }
      
  }
        }

Comment: i'm trying for using sharedPreferences and database but still not works for me.. really need that works for my college final project..

Answer (score 1):

You could send an intent to your activity with an extra, and the activity could read this extra and, if present, `finish()` itself.

Regards, 
  Stéphane